# What is best practice when registering new users on an Identity Server 4 based infrastructure?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am in the process of adding an Identity Server 4 implementation to serve authentication and authorization for a ASP.NET Core Web API. Clients will be a native iOS app, and MVC web app and potentially an Angular SPA later down the line.

I am able to provide tokens on an « offline access » basis to the iOS client using AppAuth - which is great.

I am just not sure about some of the **architectural choices** to make:

1/ where should the registration of new users take place? The literature recommends that the IS4 server be limited to login and logout endpoints, for security purposes. Does that mean that the clients or the APIs should handle creation of users in the store? I thought the whole point of IS4 was that clients and APIs don’t have access to the store? It would seem logical that the addition and modification of users  be handled by the only part of the system that has access to the store, no?

2/ is it safe to persist (1) tokens (2) the user store and (3) business data ok the same database - different tables but same database on same server? Is it better to separate databases?

3/ is it safe to have the Identity server app hosted on a sub domain to the domain where the client app will live? The API is already on another sub domain on this same domain.

Thanks

Comment: all your authorization and authentication requests should go through your IDP, if you are including 3rd party authentication (google, microsoft etc) your IDP will redirect to the external provider. If you are doing your own authentication/authorization, you will need to implement a userstore which you can do in your IDP or a seperate API, I don't see a problem with it being in your IDP but I guess it depends on how strict you want to be with seperating your concerns. One major benefit of an IDP is federation, linking users who use multiple different login methods to the one user account

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I haven’t looked into federation yet but - it sounds very powerful. As you may have gathered I am not a professional developer and this is all fairly new to me, your comments and answers all help with my learning curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1/ where should the registration of new users take place? The literature recommends that the IS4 server be limited to login and logout endpoints, for security purposes. Does that mean that the clients or the APIs should handle creation of users in the store? I thought the whole point of IS4 was that clients and APIs don’t have access to the store? It would seem logical that the addition and modification of users be handled by the only part of the system that has access to the store, no?

You can extend IDS4 to add user management. Per [IDS4 docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/big_picture.html?highlight=create%20user#how-identityserver4-can-help) it is a middleware that adds the spec compliant OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 endpoints to an arbitrary ASP.NET Core application. But this doesnt mean that you can not extend it. [Here](https://damienbod.com/2016/11/18/extending-identity-in-identityserver4-to-manage-users-in-asp-net-core/) is a sample.

> 2/ is it safe to persist (1) tokens (2) the user store and (3) business data ok the same database - different tables but same database on same server? Is it better to separate databases?

This depends more to your deployment model and your considerations for availability and scalability rather than safety. I suggest you to read more  [here](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/deployment.html) to be able to make the best decision.

> 3/ is it safe to have the Identity server app hosted on a sub domain to the domain where the client app will live? The API is already on another sub domain on this same domain.

This again has nothing to do with safety as is more of availability/scalability matter

Comment: Many thanks, this is very helpful. I have been following the QuickStarts and one of them has me adding an Asp.Net Identity user store to the Identity Server project, so i will just carry on with that and add user management to the same project.

Answer (score 0):

I have thoughts as following:

---

- 1/ where should the registration of new users take place? The
  literature recommends that the IS4 server be limited to login and
  logout endpoints, for security purposes. Does that mean that the
  clients or the APIs should handle creation of users in the store? I
  thought the whole point of IS4 was that clients and APIs don’t have
  access to the store? It would seem logical that the addition and
  modification of users be handled by the only part of the system that
  has access to the store, no?
- Suggestion: If I am starting applications from scratch and there is no existing interface for user registration, then I will prefer to provide user registration flow as part of IdS.

---

- 2/ is it safe to persist (1) tokens (2) the user store and (3)
  business data ok the same database - different tables but same
  database on same server? Is it better to separate databases?
- Suggestion: Both options are fine, but best one, is one, which suitable to your application architecture. For example if I have Service oriented or Microservice architecture, then separate database is more feasible. But if you have only one application as user registration point and other applications will use that database as user store, then it is already part of an application database. I may prefer to have IdS tables in separate Database until, unless there is some limitation.

---

- 3/ is it safe to have the Identity server app hosted on a sub domain
  to the domain where the client app will live? The API is already on
  another sub domain on this same domain.
- Suggestion: if you are serving multiple organizations, then IdS can be on different domain, otherwise, it is generally practiced to be on sub domain.